# Every time there is a constructor is called " parent::__construct(); " on model,and controller. why it is used for?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the constructor invocation. There is nothing is passed or no function is called in constructor. why it is called?

```
class admin_login_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

**on controller**

```
class admin_login extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // if(!$this->session->userdata('validated')) redirect('admin/admin_login');
}

}
```

Comment: Just a note your class names should have first letter upper case `Admin_login.php` and class `Admin_login extends CI_Controller {}` as per the user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world the same applies for your models http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Comment: This also may help class constructors http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking every page user session exist or not .like this .if you use the constructor .when every page calling constructor execute first and give out put true. then go to the function so that there we checking user session exist or not like this checking

Answer (score 0):

See the "extends" keyword on all your controller and model classes. It's basic OOP or object oriented programming. Extends means the class you create uses functionallity and attributes declared in the extended class. But to do so, the extended class must also be instantiated. Is that understandable? It's a basic pattern of OOP.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)